# How to select rows where fields change

Tags: sql

I have data similar to the following:

| Version | ID | Reviewer | Action | Decision_Type | Review_start_time | Review_end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | ABC123 | Bob | Approve | Reactive | 2021-03-31 16:49:16.0 | 2021-03-31 20:10:06.0 |
| 2 | ABC123 | Bob | Block | Pre-Publish | 2021-03-31 16:49:16.0 | 2021-03-31 20:09:29.0 |
| 1 | ABC123 | System | InProgress | Pre-Publish | 2021-03-31 16:49:16.0 | 2021-03-31 17:50:52.0 |

I need to be able to query IDs where:

1. The reviewer was Bob
2. Changes from Action = Block & Decision_Type = Pre-Publish to Action = Approve & Decision_Type = Reactive

(NOTE: the version numbers will change depending on how many reviews were completed, this is just an example)

Comment: Do you only want records where the next version matches that change, or should it return records where the statuses changed to that but not necessarily in one version?

Comment: Good question - it should return records where the statuses change from Block/Pre-publish to Approve/Reactive. I *think* it should always change in the next version, but I suppose it might not always follow that pattern.

Comment: Alright. Also, which db software are you using? ie. Sql-Server, MySQL, etc. Please tag your post.

Comment: Is the Version column supposed to indicate order?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table to itself on the ID and Reviewer and test for the presence of both kinds of records:

```
Select b.id, b.reviewer
From MyTable b Inner Join MyTable a On b.id=a.id and b.reviewer=a.reviewer
Where b.Action = 'Block' and b.Decision_Type = 'Pre-Publish'
      and a.Action = 'Approve' and a.Decision_Type = 'Reactive'
      and b.review_end_time<a.review-end-time
```

I added a requirement to the Where to ensure Approve came after Block using review end.  Based on your comment it seems you cannot be certain that the Approve' comes directly after, just somewhere after.

Comment: Note that double quotes are for delimited identifiers in (general) ANSI SQL. Use single quotes for string literals.

Comment: There is actually a field for review time, would it be better to use that?

Comment: @CESE, do you mean the `Version` _column_?

Comment: @jarlh - no, there are columns for review_start_time and review_end_time. Both in this format: 2021-03-31 16:49:16.0. I didn't include all fields in the table.

Comment: @CESE, those columns should have been included too.

Comment: @jarlh - Updated with those columns

Comment: Sorry for the quoting mistake,  I fixed it.